# How to pass function as the parameter of another function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I realize that there are already too many questions about my question but the answers I have seen so far assumes the return values of the function that is to be a pointer, `int` value.

I have two functions, namely `void binarycheck(int encoding, product *curr[], int totalcurr)` and `void search_show()`.

`binarycheck` basically gets the `encoding` value from the array struct named `curr` (curr contains mixed variables of strings and int). Its purpose is to classify the array `curr` into 3 major types and 5 subclasses after checking the `encoding` of each array curr via bitwise function.

The subclasses are included within the typedef struct that was used to form `curr`. Like:

```
typedef struct nodebase{
    char name[254];
    char company_name[254];
    int encoding;
    double price;
    struct nodebase *next;
    struct nodebase *Class;
}product;
```

Now, after using the `binarycheck` function, `void search_show` will basically ask user for his preferred 1) Type then 2) Subclass then `void search_show` will print the products that has been classified as the user's chosen Type and Subclass.

So, `void search_show` will have to use the results of `void binarycheck` that are in forms of int (for counting the presence of each classified arrays) and arrays (for classifying data).

I was thinking of a "brute force" way by putting all variables used by `void binarycheck` as the parameter of `void search_show` but the variables are too much to add.

Can anyone help me how to "re-use" all the variables and the results of the first function in the second function?

*I am using Tiny C on Windows

Sample Code:
//Binarycheck will contain variables shown below:

```
void *binarycheck(int encoding, hero *curr[], int totalwarrior)
{
int toughtotal = 0;
int nimbletotal = 0;
int smarttotal = 0;
int skeptictotal = 0;
int mystictotal = 0;
int cursedtotal = 0;
int brutetotal = 0;
int shreddertotal = 0;
int vanillatotal = 0;
int typetotal = 0;
int class_num = 0;
int class_total[6];
int total = 0;
hero *type[3][6] = {{0},{0}};
hero *smart[3][6] = {{0},{0}};
hero *nimble[3][6]= {{0},{0}};
hero *tough[3][6]= {{0},{0}};   
hero *skeptic[]= {0};
hero *mystic[]= {0};
hero *cursed[]= {0};
hero *brute[]= {0};
hero *shredder[]= {0};
hero *vanilla[]= {0};

//This is a sample of assigning "curr[totalwarrior]' into its respective type array.
if ((encoding&128)==1 && (encoding&64)==1)
{
    smart[smarttotal][class_num] = curr[totalwarrior]; //class_num is 0 as of this moment. 
    total = smarttotal;
    type[total][class_num] = smart[smarttotal][class_num];
    smarttotal++;
    printf("\n::|Smart Type::|\n");
}
/*There will be 2 more of this code (above) since there will be 3 types array*/

//This is assigning "type[total][class_num]" into its respective class array.

if ((encoding&32)==1)
{
    class_num = 1;
    type[total][class_num] = vanilla[vanillatotal];
    class_total[1] = vanillatotal;
    vanillatotal++; //Vanilla
    printf("\n::|Vanilla Class::|\n");
}
/*There will be 5 more of this code (above) since there will be 6 class array*/
```

The `seach_show` has to use `total`, `class_num`, `type[total][class_num]`,`class_total`

Comment: Is there any code you can share with us? It might make the problem clearer.

Comment: You keep referring to the "return value" of the first function, i.e. of `binarycheck`, but you repeatedly show `binarycheck` to be a void function.  That means it will have no return value.  You need to clarify exactly what you expect search_show to see.  It's likely you just want to pass a structure around between the functions.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thank you for letting me know. I got confused with `return value` with `results of the function`

Comment: `struct *curr[]` does not look like a valid parameter definition. Did you mean to write `struct nodebase *curr[]`?

Comment: @WernerHenze My apologies. I fixed `struct` with `product`

Comment: Why not encapsulate all the variables defined at the beginning of `binarycheck` into another structure, and pass that structure to both functions?

Comment: @Nikhil What do yoy mean by encapsulating them? I am just a beginner in C. I am sorry but can you show me an example?

Comment: I will have to add an answer for this, example will be too big for comment.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure in your sample code you want all those `&&` to be `&`.  `&&` is logical comparison while `&` is bitwise comparision.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Oh my gosh, I totally forgot about that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming all the variables defined at the start of `binarycheck` are the ones that you will need to pass to both functions.

So why not create a structure like this:

```
struct Parameters {
  int toughtotal;
  int nimbletotal;
  int smarttotal;
  int skeptictotal;
  int mystictotal;
  int cursedtotal;
  int brutetotal;
  int shreddertotal;
  int vanillatotal;
  int typetotal;
  int class_num;
  int class_total[6];
  int total;
  hero *type[3][6];
  hero *smart[3][6];
  hero *nimble[3][6];
  hero *tough[3][6];
  hero *skeptic[];
  hero *mystic[];
  hero *cursed[];
  hero *brute[];
  hero *shredder[];
  hero *vanilla[];
};
```

You will then need a function like `init_parameters(struct Parameters* p)` which will initialize each member of your structure as you have done at the start of `binarycheck`.

Finally called you functions like this:

```
void binarycheck(struct Parameters *p, int encoding, product *curr[], int totalcurr)
void search_show(struct Parameters *p)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of creating the Struct and use it as parameter!

Comment: Shouldn't `init_parameters(struct Parameters* p)` be `(Parameters* p)` instead? And what happens if I change `struct Parameters` into `typedef struct Parameters`?

Comment: I haven't type-def'ed the struct, hence I must use the full notation of `struct Parameters`. If I add code like `typedef Parameters parameters`, then I can do `init_parameters(parameters *p)`. You can also add the typedef along with the `struct` definition as you have done with `struct nodebase { ... } product`.

Comment: All right! I tried using your code and I am currently facing problem in initializing p->skeptic[] = {0}; Error says identifier expected

Comment: @BeginnerC Do you know in advance the number of 'skeptic', 'mystic', 'cursed', etc heroes you want? The problem is you cannot _assign_ an empty array element like this `p->skeptic[] = { 0 }` but you can initialize it, as you had done in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

This may be way off.  I'm still not certain of what you're asking.  But my suggestion needs better formatting than comments provide.

It sounds to me like you're just looking for another structure that you want to pass between functions.  Create it, pass it into `binarycheck` to fill, and then pass it into `search_show` to make use of.  Your structure would include what you're referring to as "all the variables used by `binaryCheck`".  Your code would go something like this:

```
typedef struct binary_check_values {
    int toughtotal;
    int nimbletotal;
    int smarttotal;
    int skeptictotal;
    int mystictotal;
    int cursedtotal;
    int brutetotal;
    int shreddertotal;
    int vanillatotal;
    int typetotal;
    int class_num;
    int class_total[6];
    int total;
    hero *type[3][6];
    hero *smart[3][6];
    hero *nimble[3][6];
    hero *tough[3][6];
    hero *skeptic[];
    hero *mystic[];
    hero *cursed[];
    hero *brute[];
    hero *shredder[];
    hero *vanilla[];
} binaryCheckValues;

binaryCheckResults(int encoding, hero *curr[], int totalWarrior, binaryCheckValues *values) {
    values->toughtotal = 0;
    values->nimbletotal = 0;
    /* etc */
}
/* ... other code ... */
search_show(values);
```

Comment: I will take note of this too. Thank you so much for your effort! This will absolutely come in handy

Comment: Is binaryCheckResults void?

Comment: @BeginnerC If your function has `return` statements with nothing after the word return, yes, it's void.  If it has anything resembling `return foo`, then no, it is not.  From what I can see, it's a void function.  The fact that you're modifying a parameter passed in to the function doesn't impact what the function is returning.